# How to install / use orafce package in postgresql 9.4?

Tags: postgresql, debian, orafce

I'm running the "official" [docker container of postgresql](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) in version 9.4. I went inside the running container and installed orafce

```
docker exec -i -t my_postgres bash
apt-get install postgresql-9.4-orafce
```

afterwards I've tried to reload and restart the `postgresql` service, as well as just restarting the whole container, but when I try out using function, which should be defined in orafce, it doesn't work.

I'm talking about a simple example from [here](http://postgres.cz/wiki/Oracle_functionality_(en)):

```
SELECT add_months(date '2005-05-31',1);  -- > 2005-06-30
SELECT last_day(date '2005-05-24');      -- > 2005-05-31
SELECT next_day(date '2005-05-24', 'monday'); -- > 2005-05-30
SELECT next_day(date '2005-05-24', 2); -- > 2005-05-30
SELECT months_between(date '1995-02-02', date '1995-01-01'); -- > 1.0322580645161
SELECT trunc(date '2005-07-12', 'iw');   -- > 2005-07-11
SELECT round(date '2005-07-12', 'yyyy'); -- > 2006-01-01
```

and this is the output I get, when simply copy-pasting those commands into phpPgAdmin into postgres/public:

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  function add_months(date, integer) does not exist
LINE 1:   SELECT add_months(date '2005-05-31',1);  -- > 2005-06-30
                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
In statement:

  SELECT add_months(date '2005-05-31',1);  -- > 2005-06-30
  SELECT last_day(date '2005-05-24');      -- > 2005-05-31
  SELECT next_day(date '2005-05-24', 'monday'); -- > 2005-05-30
  SELECT next_day(date '2005-05-24', 2); -- > 2005-05-30
  SELECT months_between(date '1995-02-02', date '1995-01-01'); -- > 1.0322580645161
  SELECT trunc(date '2005-07-12', 'iw');   -- > 2005-07-11
  SELECT round(date '2005-07-12', 'yyyy'); -- > 2006-01-01
```

Now, I'm aware, I shouldn't directly install packages inside docker, nor using phpPgAdmin, this is just a simple test to see if I can port a smaller oracle DB to postgres.

Is there anything I'm missing in order to be able to use orafce? I couldn't find any errors when installing the package or restarting the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a smple

```
CREATE EXTENSION orafce
```

is enough

Comment: Why do it works? Is this extension compiled aside postgresql default package the postgresql just have to enable it or in somehow postgresql download required deps when you run this command?

Comment: Ok, it [must to be installed on the machine](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.html) then you just need to tell postgresql to load it